# Como usar o comando netstat?

Tags: cmd

Estou testando no meu computador local uma aplicação java, mas não consigo subir minha aplicação porque a porta 8080 está sendo usada por algum serviço que eu não sei qual é.

Como faço para saber qual é o serviço que está rodando na porta 8080 com o comando **netstat**?

Eu tentei dessa forma, mas não deu certo:

```
Wladimir@wlady MINGW64 ~/Desktop/anotação sql postgre (master)
$ netstat -nabo
A opera▒▒o solicitada requer eleva▒▒o.

Wladimir@wlady MINGW64 ~/Desktop/anotação sql postgre (master)
$ netstat -nabo | find "8080"
find: ‘8080’: No such file or directory

Wladimir@wlady MINGW64 ~/Desktop/anotação sql postgre (master)
$
```

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar este comando:

> *netstat -nabo*

Você também pode filtrar por algum texto adicionando *| find "texto"*.

**Exemplo:**

> *netstat -nabo | find "8080"*

Ou dependendo do prompt de comando:

> *netstat -nabo | findstr "8080"*

Porém não irá trazer todas as informações do primeiro comando.

**Obs:** use o cmd como administrador.

Comment: eu atualizei minha postagem poderia dá uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Parece que você está usando o gitbash. O find funciona no cmd padrão do Windows, no gitbash ao invés do find, utilize findstr. Note a mensagem "A opera▒▒o solicitada requer eleva▒▒o", execute seu prompt de comando como administrador para evitar problemas.